# Make a Export button that copy's query table to a new workbook in desktp and removes data connections

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Hello I have for sheets in a workbook with each sheet having its own query table from MySQL. These sheets also have some user form button on them like refresh, Go to first row etc. They also have few calculated columns.

I want to create a Export button that makes a copy (paste only values) of the entire workbook without the data connections and form buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will run through all existing sheets in your workbook, it will copy the entire sheets cells (**values only**, without Form Controls or links) , and will paste them in the same structure to another workbook that is saved on the *Desktop*.

```
Sub ExportCleanDataSheets()

Dim Sht             As Worksheet
Dim DestSht         As Worksheet
Dim DesktopPath     As String
Dim NewWbName       As String
Dim Wb              As Workbook
Dim i               As Long

Set Wb = Workbooks.Add

' set path to Dektop
DesktopPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"

' modify the name (I used "Clean_SQL_Data" and current date and time) to your needs
' i like to use the full date and time format, this way I don;t overwrite old files
NewWbName = "Clean_SQL_Data " & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd _hh_mm_ss")
i = 1

' scroll through all sheets and copy the values only to the new workbook
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If i <= Wb.Sheets.Count Then
        Set DestSht = Wb.Sheets(i)
    Else
        Set DestSht = Wb.Sheets.Add
    End If

    Sht.Cells.Copy
    With DestSht
        .Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        .Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        .Name = Sht.Name
    End With

    i = i + 1
Next Sht

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Wb.SaveAs Filename:=DesktopPath & NewWbName, FileFormat:=xlNormal
Wb.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @user2704742 when you step into the code, what line are you getting the error ?

Comment: Wb.Sheets(i).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: It stops at the second sheet, also dates are copied as number. Is it possible to copy the format excluding only formulas.

Comment: @user2704742 try edited code (to also copy the Formats)

Comment: Excellent..Works well but only one issue, it doesn't copy the sheet name like it did on the previous code. Is it possible to make the new workbook have the same sheet names?

Comment: Thank you SIR!! Your a STAR :)